# I'm struggling with this question...have tried many different approaches but to no avail

Tags: sql

I'm prepping for a job interview and got stumped by this question...

```
-- Take the 5 lowest paid employees who have done at least 10 projects
-- Given Tables:
-- Table 1: Employees
-- ID | Salary

-- Table 2: Projects
-- Employee_id | project_id | Start_dt | End_dt
```

I was trying to use a sub-query to first select the folks with Projects greater than 10. However, not sure how to incorporate salary into the main query.

Comment: First, what DB are you using? (as the sql tag says to add) ... and post the queries that you tried to use.

Comment: Not a good title for a question. Please edit the title to reflect your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you a pseudo SQL to solve this. If you can specify the database I can try to provide you with exact sql.

```
Left outer join Projects table with Employee both tables and
Create a index/rank/row number order by descending on Salary 
put above query in a subquery with calculated column e.g. rnk
In outer query do a group by on Employee_id and Project_Id
Filter the group by rnk<= 5 and Max(End_dt) is not null and Count(*) >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ID
FROM Employees e
JOIN Products p 
ON e.ID = p.Employee_id
WHERE end_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING COUNT(p.project_id) > 9
ORDER BY e.Salary
LIMIT 5;
```